# How to check session in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, session-variables

I am starting work with CakePHP 3.x but when i am trying to check session variable first time, getting following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function check() on null
```

i am using following code

```
$this->request->session->check('admin')
```

The above working fine in CakePHP 2.x but getting error in CakePHP 3.x.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$this->request->session()->check()`.

`session()->` instead of `session->`.

Docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object